# Multithreaded program C using multiple .cpp files

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I have a multi threaded program in C that was working well but was in one single main.cpp file.

I have moved the thread in another .cpp file and added it's signature, void* displayScreen(void*); , in the header. I include the header in my initial main.cpp file.

Compiling works but the linker returns an error when trying to call pthread_create(): undefined reference to `displayScreen(void*)'

It looks like it compiled displayScreen(void *) fine but does not know where to load it from. Is there a way for me to tell the linker where to find it or am I doing it wrong please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Post the commands you used to compile and link or this can't be answered.

Comment: your error message makes no sense - linkers don't "call" functions.  Did you remember to include _both_ object files in the compiled target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the signature alone lets you *compile* the main translation unit, but you still have to compile the implementation of the function separately and *link* the two:

**main.cpp**

```
void* displayScreen(void*);

int main()
{
  /* .... */
}
```

**display.cpp**

```
void* displayScreen(void*)
{
  /* implementation */
}
```

**Compile:**

```
g++ -O2 -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -O2 -o display.o display.cpp
```

**Link:**

```
g++ -o myprogram main.o display.o -lpthread -s
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a really dumb mistake. I was trying to compile the header file, the .h, and not the .cpp code. I did not notice my error. sorry!